# Regular matrices references

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, reference-request

Can someone suggest me a book or a lecture note which covers regular matrices with all theories related to it? Any assistance will be much appreciated. (By regular I mean some power of the matrix is positive)

Answer (score 2):

You may have a look on [this book](http://books.google.fr/books?id=MRB7SUc_u6YC&lpg=PP1&hl=cs&pg=PP1#v=onepage&q&f=false), which is a great resource concerning nonnegative matrices and related topics. Otherwise, any a bit more serious book on stochastic processes and Markov chains would be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Here are just a few resources that I found:

This is a useful handout from MIT: [Matrices](http://web.mit.edu/2.14/www/Handouts/Matrices.pdf)

It isn't great on its own but it's a great resource to reference to if you can't remember something from your lectures.

---

I use this book: [Mathematical Methods for Physics and Engineering](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Mathematical-Methods-Physics-Engineering-Comprehensive/dp/0521679710/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1399372185&sr=8-1&keywords=mathematical%20methods%20for%20physics%20and%20engineering)

It contains a good 70% of the maths that I require for my Physics degree.
It has a good 80 pages on matrices and is great if you want to build upon a basic understanding of them.

---

After a quick google search I found this book: [Matrix Analysis and Applied Algebra Solutions](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Matrix-Analysis-Applied-Algebra-Solutions/dp/0898714540)

The final chapter of this book covers regular matrices and it looks like it also covers matrices related topics that I can think of off of the top of my head.

---

Here are some lecture notes from Harvard that focus on regular matrices: [Markov Matrices](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~knill/teaching/math19b_2011/handouts/lecture33.pdf)

---

The Wikipedia article on regular matrices is a little wordy but very useful: [Stochastic Matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_matrix)

---

There is a more in-depth resource on regular matrices written by The University of New Mexico here: [Stochastic Matrices](https://www.cs.unm.edu/~williams/cs530/markov4.pdf)

---

Obviously some of these books are expensive. I hear that with some nifty internet skills there are PDF's available, although I do not endorse that kind of behaviour. If you cannot afford these books it is likely that they (or some similar books) will be available in a university's library.

I hope this helps!
Sean.

EDIT: added the resources that I posted in the comments.

Comment: Thanks Sean for providing all the resources